# Switch fields order in Easy Digital Downloads checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

I'd like to switch the order of the 'Billing City' and the 'Billing ZIP' field in the code below through a snippet in my functions.php file. I've been on it for hours, but I can't get it right. This is the code in the easy-digital-downloads/includes/checkout/template.php file, thank you so much for helping out:

```
<?php
do_action( 'edd_after_cc_fields' );

echo ob_get_clean();
}
add_action( 'edd_cc_form', 'edd_get_cc_form' );

/**
 * Outputs the default credit card address fields
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @return void
 */
function edd_default_cc_address_fields() {

    $logged_in = is_user_logged_in();
    $customer  = EDD()->session->get( 'customer' );
    $customer  = wp_parse_args( $customer, array( 'address' => array(
        'line1'   => '',
        'line2'   => '',
        'city'    => '',
        'zip'     => '',
        'state'   => '',
        'country' => ''
    ) ) );

    $customer['address'] = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $customer['address'] );

    if( $logged_in ) {

        $user_address = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_edd_user_address', true );

        foreach( $customer['address'] as $key => $field ) {

            if ( empty( $field ) && ! empty( $user_address[ $key ] ) ) {
                $customer['address'][ $key ] = $user_address[ $key ];
            } else {
                $customer['address'][ $key ] = '';
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Billing Address Details.
     *
     * Allows filtering the customer address details that will be pre-populated on the checkout form.
     *
     * @since 2.8
     *
     * @param array $address The customer address.
     * @param array $customer The customer data from the session
     */
    $customer['address'] = apply_filters( 'edd_checkout_billing_details_address', $customer['address'], $customer );

    ob_start(); ?>
    <fieldset id="edd_cc_address" class="cc-address">
        <legend><?php _e( 'Billing Details', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?></legend>
        <?php do_action( 'edd_cc_billing_top' ); ?>
        <p id="edd-card-address-wrap">
            <label for="card_address" class="edd-label">
                <?php _e( 'Billing Address', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>
                <?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_address' ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="edd-description"><?php _e( 'The primary billing address for your credit card.', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?></span>
            <input type="text" id="card_address" name="card_address" class="card-address edd-input<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_address' ) ) { echo ' required'; } ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Address line 1', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['address']['line1']; ?>"<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_address' ) ) {  echo ' required '; } ?>/>
        </p>
        <p id="edd-card-address-2-wrap">
            <label for="card_address_2" class="edd-label">
                <?php _e( 'Billing Address Line 2 (optional)', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>
                <?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_address_2' ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="edd-description"><?php _e( 'The suite, apt no, PO box, etc, associated with your billing address.', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?></span>
            <input type="text" id="card_address_2" name="card_address_2" class="card-address-2 edd-input<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_address_2' ) ) { echo ' required'; } ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Address line 2', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['address']['line2']; ?>"<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_address_2' ) ) {  echo ' required '; } ?>/>
        </p>
        <p id="edd-card-city-wrap">
            <label for="card_city" class="edd-label">
                <?php _e( 'Billing City', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>
                <?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_city' ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="edd-description"><?php _e( 'The city for your billing address.', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?></span>
            <input type="text" id="card_city" name="card_city" class="card-city edd-input<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_city' ) ) { echo ' required'; } ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'City', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['address']['city']; ?>"<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_city' ) ) {  echo ' required '; } ?>/>
        </p>
        <p id="edd-card-zip-wrap">
            <label for="card_zip" class="edd-label">
                <?php _e( 'Billing Zip / Postal Code', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>
                <?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_zip' ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="edd-description"><?php _e( 'The zip or postal code for your billing address.', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?></span>
            <input type="text" size="4" id="card_zip" name="card_zip" class="card-zip edd-input<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_zip' ) ) { echo ' required'; } ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Zip / Postal Code', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['address']['zip']; ?>"<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_zip' ) ) {  echo ' required '; } ?>/>
        </p>
        <p id="edd-card-country-wrap">
            <label for="billing_country" class="edd-label">
                <?php _e( 'Billing Country', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>
                <?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'billing_country' ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="edd-description"><?php _e( 'The country for your billing address.', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?></span>
            <select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'edd-country-field-nonce' ); ?>" class="billing_country edd-select<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'billing_country' ) ) { echo ' required'; } ?>"<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'billing_country' ) ) {  echo ' required '; } ?>>
                <?php

                $selected_country = edd_get_shop_country();

                if( ! empty( $customer['address']['country'] ) && '*' !== $customer['address']['country'] ) {
                    $selected_country = $customer['address']['country'];
                }

                $countries = edd_get_country_list();
                foreach( $countries as $country_code => $country ) {
                  echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $country_code ) . '"' . selected( $country_code, $selected_country, false ) . '>' . $country . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p id="edd-card-state-wrap">
            <label for="card_state" class="edd-label">
                <?php _e( 'Billing State / Province', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>
                <?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_state' ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="edd-description"><?php _e( 'The state or province for your billing address.', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?></span>
            <?php
            $selected_state = edd_get_shop_state();
            $states         = edd_get_shop_states( $selected_country );

            if( ! empty( $customer['address']['state'] ) ) {
                $selected_state = $customer['address']['state'];
            }

            if( ! empty( $states ) ) : ?>
            <select name="card_state" id="card_state" class="card_state edd-select<?php if( edd_field_is_required( 'card_state' ) ) { echo ' required'; } ?>">
                <?php
                    foreach( $states as $state_code => $state ) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $state_code . '"' . selected( $state_code, $selected_state, false ) . '>' . $state . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <?php else : ?>
            <?php $customer_state = ! empty( $customer['address']['state'] ) ? $customer['address']['state'] : ''; ?>
            <input type="text" size="6" name="card_state" id="card_state" class="card_state edd-input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $customer_state ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'State / Province', 'easy-digital-downloads' ); ?>"/>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
        <?php do_action( 'edd_cc_billing_bottom' ); ?>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'edd-checkout-address-fields', 'edd-checkout-address-fields-nonce', false, true ); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
add_action( 'edd_after_cc_fields', 'edd_default_cc_address_fields' );
```

Comment: Just to understand it better: i don't know that plugin but if that's a template file, shouldn't it be replaceable by copying it to your theme so that you can edit it as you like? If the overwrite works it should be quite easy to swap the order, just a matter of cut + paste the code.
Edit: see here (https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/279-customizing-the-checkout-cart-template)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out! That only works for the checkout_cart.php file under easy-digital-downloads/templates, not for this file that is under easy-digital-downloads/includes/checkout/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your comments i would say the EASIEST (not the cleanest) way to achieve that is to include a small piece of JS to move the DIV

```
$("#edd-card-zip-wrap").insertBefore("#edd-card-city-wrap");
```

That should be enought :)

Edit:
Paste this code into your theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_script' );
function enqueue_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js', array( "jquery" ), false, true );
}
```

This will search for a file named "my-script.js" that lives in the root folder of your theme (same level as the functions.php file)
That file content can be something like this:

Edited with fixed wait:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var waitThisTime = 1000; // Wait this ms. 1000ms = 1sec
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#edd-card-zip-wrap").insertBefore("#edd-card-city-wrap");
    },waitThisTime);
});
```

Comment: Hi there Diego, thanks for helping out! Where do I insert this? I don't want to modify the file itself, so I'd prefer to do it through functions.php.

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for editing you answer, didn't notice it until now : ) I have a +50 reputation bounty ready that expires in 4 days, but when I try your solution, it doesn't work... What's going wrong?

Comment: What doesn't actually work? Does the custom .js file gets included in your page? can you add a console log into the JS code to see if it's working?

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for your feedback. I looked into the console with developer tools and saw this for the JS file: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

Comment: Does that error comes exactly from the file you added? is that related to those 2 lines of code i've posted? Because if you have another JS error in your page and that script comes before the one u've included to move the div then the latter will not work

Comment: Hi Diego, it says on the same line 'my-script.js' so I'm pretty sure its an error in that file.

Comment: Im sorry, wrote it real quick inside SO directly and missed some parenthesis. Try it now :)

Comment: Other error this time: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at my-script.js?ver=5.5.1:1

Comment: Ok, there's a quick fix for that, replace all the "$" with "jQuery"

Comment: No more errors anymore, but it doesn't work... You can check for yourself: go to https://leden.stefaanoyen.be/downloads/klanten-kiezen-jou-promo/, click on the button and check the 'Factuuradres - plaats' and 'Factuuradres - postcode' fields. They should be inversed...

Comment: It's all clear now. Your fields appear AFTER the page load (that means they get rendered by some sort of Javascript code). So that snippet i gave you CANT work, because when document is ready (see document.ready(...)) the fields doesn't exists. 
The proof that my code actually work if the fields exist is that once the page loads you can open developer tools (if you are using Google Chrome it's a matter of right click in any area of the page and click "inspect" in the context menù). You will find a console tab in dev tools, paste the code and see it works :)

Comment: All right, that explains a lot. So JS can't offer a solution then? Should probably go through a PHP snippet in functions.php then, but I can't figure that out.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty, Diego, because you kept trying to help. Thank you for that : ) Do you see any other possible solutions?

Comment: There are different possibilities but they all depend on how the JS in your page loads the checkout fields. What you tecnically need to do is make the code i've pasted "wait" until the fields are present in the page. If the code that renders them is well-made then it may be possible w/o any hack, else i can propose an hack-ish way to do that but that would not be so good, clear and well made. More like a "last chance attemp"

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for trying to help out! How do I make that code wait? I have zero experience with JS : )

Comment: I updated my answer but that is just an example, it might even work but that IS NOT 100% accurate. You may choose an arbitrary amount of time (even 2sec for example) but that may be WAY too much for some1 before actually seeing the code being executed or too short for somebody else. It actually depends on 2 factor, the speed of the AJAX code that renders the field to get the response from the server and the speed of the client device that needs to perform JS operations

Comment: That did the trick, Diego! Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it : )

Comment: Glad it worked but perform some extended tests, it maybe enough for your connection + pc but it maybe way too much or still not enough for somebody else. That's a trick as you correctly said ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by using below code snippet.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ro_postcode_city_interchange' );
 
function ro_postcode_city_interchange( $checkout_fields ) {
    $checkout_fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 70;
    $checkout_fields['billing']['billing_city']['priority'] = 90;
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

This code snipper will interchange the order as all fields have their priority so here you have to give `postcode` priority of `city` and `city` priority of `zipcode`.

Tested and works well.